# Using SED to append a string to an existing line of text?

Tags: regex, linux, text, replace, sed

I'm trying to use the linux sed command to append a path element to the RewriteBase in a .htaccess file.

I have tried it with this arguments:

```
#current RewriteBase is "RewriteBase /mypath"
sed -ie 's/RewriteBase\(.*\)/RewriteBase \1\/add/g' .htaccess
```

with this result:

```
addriteBase /mypath
```

So sed overwrites the the beginning of the replacement string with the last string.

Why is that?

Another question would be how to prevent to have 2 slashes when the RewriteBase is just "/".

```
RewriteBase /
```

will become

```
RewriteBase //add
```

but should be

```
RewriteBase /add
```

Is there any way to prevent this? If not I can run a second sed command replacing all double slashes with a single one. But maybe there is a more elegant way to do this.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is sed including the `\r` in the result, making it *look* as though the text is being stuck to the beginning. Shove your file through `dos2unix` before putting it through sed.

As for the second part, you need to capture the optional slash outside the group, then put in `/add`.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is append some text to the line, you don't need backreferences.  Try this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/^M//g;s|RewriteBase.*|&/add|' .htaccess
```

The special `&` character represents everything that matched in the pattern space.

#### Note:

The `s/^M//g` part is the sed equivalent to `dos2unix` and the `^M` is created by typing `<ctrl+v><ctrl+m>`.

Comment: Instead of Ctrl-v, Ctrl-m you can just use `\r`: `sed /\r//` (the `g` is not likely to be needed). Here's an alternative to the second part: `/RewriteBase/ s|$|/add|`